# integration by substitution of multiple variables

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, substitution

I have an integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}
\end{equation}

where $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. I also know

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}f(\mathbf{u})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}.
\end{equation}

For $n=m$, we have

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} = \frac{1}{\det\mathbf{B}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{u})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}. 
\end{equation}

What do I do for $n\neq m$?

Comment: You should mention what $X$ and $U$ are

Comment: Ok, I changed the sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you learn nothing about $I_1 := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(Bx)dx$ by knowing $I_2 := \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} f(u)du$ when $n\neq m$.  This is for geometric reasons:

- If $m>n$, then $I_1$ integrates just "one slice" of the integral $I_2$, which is a set of measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and so can be anything at all.  For example, if $n=1$ and $m=2$ and $f$ is the characteristic function of a rectangle $[0,1]\times [0,2]$, then $I_2 = 2$, but $I_1$ can be anything from $1$ to $\sqrt{5}$ depending on $B$.  If we made $f$ the characteristic function of the line $0\times [0,1]$, then $I_2 = 0$ and $I_1 = 1$ if $B = \left(1 \:\: 0 \right)^T$ but $I_1=0$ if $B$ has any non-zero second entry.
- On the other hand, $m < n$, then the integral $I_1$ generally won't converge at all, because there are infinitely many points taking on every non-zero value of the integrand.  For example if $m=1$ and $n=2$ with $f$ being the characteristic function of the interval $[0,1]$, then for a $B$ like $\left(1\:\: 0\right)$ we see that $f(Bx)$ is the characteristic function of $[0,1]\times[-\infty,\infty]$, which has infinite area.

There is, however, some relationship between these integrals.  In the case where $m>n$, we can consider comparing the integral $I_1$ with the surface integral in $\mathbb{R}^m$ over the slice spanned by $B$.  Here there is a formula analogous to the one you mention, involving the "[Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)" of $B$.  Here it is:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(Bx)dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det{B^T B}}} \int_{R(B)} f(u)du$$

where $R(B)$ stands for the range of $B$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$.  I recommend chapter 8 of [this book](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~sjamaar/manifolds/manifold.pdf) for reference.

Comment: Thanks! That actually makes a lot sense in my application!

Comment: I cannot find this formula anywhere but here. Can you please tell me where to find it? Thanks!

Comment: @JennyReiningerhe What are you asking?  I linked two references in the text, one of which is a textbook with pretty much all the details.

Comment: I cannot find the actual equation in the text...

Comment: @JennyReininger No reference is likely to have the exact formula, because your question concerns a rather specialized case.  But your case follows from more general theorems of integration on manifolds, which are contained in the cited reference.  In particular, section 8.3 defines a volume form which contains the expected Gramian factor.

Comment: @JennyReininger If you just want intuition, though, section 8.1 of the reference (and theorem 8.4 in particular) contains a derivation of the Gramian factor, which is just the scaling of volume induced by a linear transformation.  If you understand this, you will understand the formula I wrote, which is essentially just a "change of variables" formula.

Comment: Can you put the equation into a citable reference?

Comment: @JennyReininger You can cite this post, I suppose.  There is a "cite" link at the bottom of the post.  Other than that, there's nothing I can do.